# Memory usage is not released in IIS express

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, zip, iis-express

I am trying to unzip a file using below code.

```
public static void UnZip(string zipFile, string folderPath)
{
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive())
    {

         //Loads the zip file.
         zip.Open(Path.GetFullPath(zipFile));

         //Saving the contents of zip file to disk.
         for (int i = 0; i < zip.Count; i++)
         {
             using (ZipArchiveItem item = zip[i])
             {
                 if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                     Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
                 string itemName = folderPath + item.ItemName;
                 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(itemName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                                       FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                 {
                    MemoryStream ms = item.DataStream as MemoryStream;
                    ms.WriteTo(fs);
                    fs.Flush();
                    ms.Close();
                 }
             }
         }
     zip.Close();
     }
}
```

My Issue :

I have published my web project and hosted in IIS Express-8. While calling this `UnZip` method Memory usage reaches more than `600MB` and it never dropdown after come out from the method more than one hour. so if i again call the same method i am getting `MemoryOutOfException` error because by default iis express have `800MB` so i am getting the error.

I don't want to increase the memory size of the `IIS Express`. May be I have did some mistake in my code but i can't find a issue.

Help me to find a issue and solve my problem.

Comment: There's no point calling `fs.Dispose()` when you're initializing `fs` in a `using` block that will call `Dispose()` automatically for you.

Comment: Wrap your MemoryStream with a using block

Comment: I tried in that case also....but not works @sievajet

Comment: Why don't you just call [ZipArchive.ExtractToDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttodirectory) instead of all this manual labor?

Comment: I am using .net4 framework. But ZipArchive.ExtractToDirectory only supports in .net4.5 framework. @jeroen

Comment: Well, it would help if you mentioned that... Without knowing what library it is, helping you will be slightly tricky. The most popular library to add zip support to .NET prior to 4.5 is [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/) (which offers `ZipInputStream`, allowing for streaming the contents without first loading it all in memory), but obviously this isn't SharpZipLib.

Answer (score 0):

I would put "zip.Close();" inside using block

Comment: Sorry, i wrongly typed in question. Now i Edited correctly. @robert